# Change the textview's text using button click in Android

Tags: android

I want to change the text on a `textView` on button click. There can be multiple buttons in activity. The main purpose is to change the name of fruit on button click either any one button is clicked.
For example: Button 1 is clicked change the name, Button 2 is clicked next name, Button 3 is clicked next name and so on. I am trying as given below but the names are not changing.

**Main Activity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView sentence_etx;
    private Button btn_1,btn_2;
    private String[] names = { "Apple","Mango","Cherry","Banana","Extra"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sentence_etx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etx_sentence);
        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);

        for (int i=0;i<=names.length;i++) {
            work(i);
        }
    }

    private void work(final int i) {
            btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sentence_etx.setText(names[i]);
                }
            });

            btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    sentence_etx.setText(names[i]);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.awais.test2.MainActivity">




    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/etx_sentence"
            android:text="Names......" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">


        <Button
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_1"
            android:text="1"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_2"
            android:text="2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/btn_3"
            android:text="3"/>

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `for` because listeners need to be set once

```
  for (int i=0;i<=names.length;i++) {
        work(i);
    }
```

so signature of `work` would be

```
 private void work() {
```

and call it once from `onCreate`

Declare `i` as global and put an `if` condition while setting the next value to avoid index bound exception

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int i=0;
    // code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // code
        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
        // initialize listener 
        work();
    }

    private void work() {
            btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // check bounds
                    if (++i<names.length) {
                        sentence_etx.setText(names[i]);                       
                    }
                    // else{ // uncomment to reset the value of i 
                    //     i=0;
                    // }
                }
            });

            btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (++i<names.length) {
                        sentence_etx.setText(names[i]);                       
                    }
                     // else{ // uncomment to reset the value of i 
                    //     i=0;
                    // }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

---

Your all `buttons` are doing same work , so you can simply have a `listener` and apply it on all `button` objects rather than creating separate anonymous listeners and

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView sentence_etx;
    private Button btn_1,btn_2;
    private String[] names = { "Apple","Mango","Cherry","Banana","Extra"};
    private int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sentence_etx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etx_sentence);
        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);

        // initialize listener 
        btn_1.setOnClickListener(listner);
        btn_2.setOnClickListener(listner);
    }

    OnClickListener listner=new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // check bounds
            if (++i<names.length) {
                sentence_etx.setText(names[i]);                       
            }
            // else{ // uncomment to reset the value of i 
            //     i=0;
            // }

            // note you can also add some conditional statement 
            // to check which button is clicked using v.getId();            
        }
    }; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reseting the `OnClickListener` of your buttons every time you call `work`. If you want them to show different names, you can't assign them the same `OnClickListener` (which is that you do right now).

What you could do is change the signature of `work` to receive the Button as a parameter and set the listener on that button. Then, in the `onCreate` method, you decide which name goes with which button

Answer (score 0):

you only need to set `OnClickListener` once

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView sentence_etx;
    private Button btn_1,btn_2;
    private String[] names = { "Apple","Mango","Cherry","Banana","Extra"};
    private int curIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sentence_etx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etx_sentence);
        btn_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
        btn_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_2);

        btn_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (curIndex == names.length - 1) {
                    curIndex = 0;
                }
                sentence_etx.setText(names[curIndex]);
                curIndex++;
            }
        });

        btn_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (curIndex == names.length - 1) {
                    curIndex = 0;
                }
                sentence_etx.setText(names[curIndex]);
                curIndex++;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `names[0] , names[1]` should be generic. The purpose is to change the names (Next name in the array) if any button is clicked.